# how to get basic scrolling in xterm

Tags: xterm, scrolling

I am using xterm on a remote Linux machine (from a local Linux machine). I just want basic scrolling, meaning that I want use the arrow keys to scroll up and down. What I get is a clunky scrolling scheme where the left and right mouse buttons cause it to jump by a page (or several lines). I can't believe that this is what most users want.

I brought up the xterm man page online, and the closest thing I found is the +j option, which says "This option indicates that xterm should not do jump scrolling." However, that did not do what I want. Is there any other way to get basic scrolling with xterm? Frankly, I am surprized that this is so hard to figure out. As far as I am concerned, it should be the default behavior.

I do not care whether the scrolling is "smooth" or not. I just don't want it to jump a page (or several lines) at a time.

Also, if there is another terminal emulator that does what I want and is available on most or all Linux distributions, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: `xterm` can let you bind key presses and releases and most other X11 events to anything you like including scrolling up or down but if arrow keys are used by the terminal emulator to scroll up and down, then terminal applications won't be able to use them for themselves (like text editors to move their cursor or shells to go back and forth in their history).

Answer (score 1):

xterm is the oldest terminal application still in default GUI distributions at all.  If you don't like the way it works, why are you using it instead of some more modern terminal application?

Having said that, xterm does do what you want.  It is just that it uses a much older scrollbar convention that while it was very flexible, was regrettably not intuitive and has been abandoned.

Here is the functionality available:

- Jump scroll is an option that changes the way xterm scrolls when text is printed in it.  With jump scroll off, the terminal scrolls one line each time a line is added.  With it on, if the display can't keep up with lines quickly added, rather than scroll one line, it "jumps" to what it would look like after all the text is added.  This takes less cpu time and keeps the buffer showing the most recent line no matter how fast lines are added.  On modern fast systems, it may be difficult to visually tell the difference.
- You can make xterm scroll back and forwards one line at a time by using the scroll wheel on the mouse.  Probably most terminal emulators do this.
- Left or right clicking in the scrollbar moves the terminal (forwards or back respectively) the amount that is the distance between the top of the scroll bar and the position you clicked.  So if you click at the top of the scrollbar, it moves by one line.  If you click at the bottom, it will move one terminal height.
- Middle clicking in the scrollbar does what modern scroll bars do if you left click directly on the indicator in the bar -- it scrolls to an absolute position and allows you to drag the position.

Comment: OK, thanks. If there are better terminal emulators out there, what are they? Sorry, I am not up to date on Linux applications, nor am I a power user. I just want something that is widely available on most or all Linux distributions and is straightforward to use.

Comment: Idunno, I just did `apt search terminal` and installed most of them and tried each one.

Comment: OK, I just tried "apt search terminal", and over 700 items came up (I ran it through wc and it had 2189 lines, with three lines per item, so over 700 items). You must have lots of time if you installed and tried most of them! I don't have that kind of time, so perhaps you can tell me which are the top two or three best choices.

Comment: Perhaps I weeded them out first.  A lot of those are not terminals, but applications that run in terminals.  I know I tried at least a dozen.

Comment: I'm much less convinced. xterm is the terminal. Other terminals have more issues: for one they pretend to be xterm, but fails to be really compatible or have all functionality we expect (and not many programs known how to deal with a `TERM=` something not starting with xterm (or other common old terminals, and this is a real problem. Also most other terminals sucks with keyboard (use irssi, screen, tmux, emacs, etc.  and you find problems with intercepted common keys).

Comment: Almost everything knows TERM=vt100 which is a subset of xterm which is a subset of xterm-256color